# Zend Framework : How can I have multiple instance of an Action Helper?

Tags: zend-framework, action, helper

I’m building a widget system based on Action Helper. Each widget deal with the segment response to modify the render view.
But , I’ve got a problem.
The widgets are calling in a Controller Plugin, in the preDispatch, like this :

```
// $widgets : list of widget to call
foreach($widgets as $segment =>$widget) {
Zend_Controller_Action_HelperBroker::addHelper(
new $widget($segment));
}
```

That’s worsk fine. But if I’ve got a same widget call twice, the widget will be calling just one time.
Example :

```
Zend_Controller_Action_HelperBroker::addHelper(
new Menu_Widget($segment=’menu’),
new Menu_Widget($segment =’right’),
);
```

If I do a dump to check the stack :

```
Zend_Debug::dump(Zend_Controller_Action_HelperBroker::getStack());
```

I can see just one time Menu_Widget in this array.

How can I have multiple instance of a same Action Helper?

Sorry for my english.

Comment: Maybe this [link](http://weierophinney.net/matthew/archives/246-Using-Action-Helpers-To-Implement-Re-Usable-Widgets.html) will give you some info.

Answer (score 0):

IMO the helper broker is made just for that - to have only one instance. I would either extend the Broker (which makes little sense) or create a class that will handle the calls.

**Update:**
Make a action/view helper. Assign widgets to it and then use it to echo the widgets.

```
// controller
foreach ($this->_helper->widget->getWidgets() as $widget) {
    $widget->setVariablesToView();
}

//view
$this->widget()->getWidget('widgetName'); //view params already set
```

Comment: Ok so I've got a big problem :(. You say "create a class", but I wonder how can i do handle the calls in this class.